# Electron console.log emitted from two different places/files?

Tags: electron, vite, xstate

I've got an electron app with vite/xstate/react. In development I'm seeing just a single `xstate.init` event emitted when starting up the app. But in production builds, I see two `xstate.init` events (there should only be one, triggered by xstate itself upon initialising):

[image]

[image]

I'm logging the event out (renderer process, so it shows up in dev tools). It comes from the same file/chunk, but for some reason, dev tools show two different paths to the same file (`file:///Users/...` vs `/Users/...`). This is causing some bad bugs where things get ran twice in some cases. I'm trying to narrow down the issue here. Is this some sort of issue with electron and the build files?

Comment: I don't see similar log messages between environments in Electron apps I've built, could there possibly be something in your code that is executing twice?

Comment: @reZach this is what I initially thought, but I haven't been able to figure out why this would only happen in production builds of my electron app, and not locally in development.

Comment: are you able to post any code you _feel_ is causing this. I'm not yet swayed it's the build process.